# Jquery element live?

Tags: javascript, jquery, live

I have some JS that needed to be on when modal popup appear in partial view?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".lbl-ui ")
 .find("select:not([multiple])").kendoDropDownList().end()
 .find("select[multiple]").kendoMultiSelect().end();
});
```

Everything working ok, when i put this js in partial view that goes in modal, but i need that JS to move to be in seperate JS file, and to waht is that element is document. I know i can use on() or live() but i have some problem with it.
What i need is to put this code somewhere else not in partial that goes in modal?

Comment: `.live()` has been long deprecated. What's the issue with `.on()`?